# Klenow fragment does not seem to have 5->3 exonuclease activity, but it can still displace nucleotides in front of him - How?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology

Klenow fragment does not seem to have 5->3 exonuclease activity, but it can still displace nucleotides in front of him - How? How would this displacement mechanism differ. My first guess is that exonuclease activity actually digests upcomming strand into single nucleotides, but how come the displacement activity not get in the way for lab work? : 
"The 5' -> 3' exonuclease activity of E. coli's DNA polymerase I makes it unsuitable for many applications. "

[image]

Why doesn't the 5->3' displacement activity make the applications troublesome then? What would those applications be.

I've spend a long time looking for these answers, but unfortunately I've found nothing.

Maybe someone has any idea:)

Cheers!

References:
Image - http://www.vivo.colostate.edu/hbooks/genetics/biotech/enzymes/klenow.html

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please provide references to images you add to your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the New England Biolabs [website](https://www.neb.com/) is a great resource for this sort of information.  Maybe you already know this: Klenow fragment is widely used in molecular biology today. The broad use of Klenow fragment is because it will remove 3' overhangs, thereby 'polishing' or 'blunting' the DNA.  See the [famous cloning techniques manual](http://www.molecularcloning.com/) for additional information.

It is a polymerase, though, and it does perform 5-->3' elongation in the presence of dNTPs.  (sidenote: Klenow was initially used in polymerase chain reaction (PCR) development, and later replaced with heat-stable Taq pol.)

The so-called 'strand displacement' activity of the enzyme allows the 5-->3 elongation of the new strand to occur even in the presence of an existing, annealed strand ahead of the advancing polymerase, as you say.  This may seem problematic at first glance, but the job of polymerase is to make a complete, templated copy of DNA -- that is why reseachers use it, and that is its job in nature too!  Stand displacement is really convenient for scientists when using random primers, for instance.  The DNA polymerization can continue unimpeded despite the presence of a 'downstream' barrier.  This is also why not having 5'-->3' exonuclease activity is helpful in this context.  (sidenote: pol I is [not the main replicative polymerase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_polymerase_I) in E. coli. and its discovery is one of the great stories of post-war biology).

I hope this addresses your question(s).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still unclear on one point - how is strand displacement activity different from 5->3 exonuclease activity. They both remove nucleotides in 5->3 direction, don't they?

Comment: a nuclease digests DNA; strand displacement is not strand digestion